# Super Large Models Not Showing in Viewport or Render

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

I'm trying to make a Flight Sim with very accurate instrumentation data (specifically location, rotation, velocities, etc) using Blender and Armory3D. To do this, I'd like to have the user's plane fly around an elliptical Earth of roughly the same size and shape.

However, when I create a 6378.1370 km by 6356.7523 km ellipse and set the z offset to -6356.7523 km, the object disappears. At that point, the top of the ellipse should be touching the world origin and should be in view, but I can't see it. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Armory3D but blender defaults to the viewing distance set to 1000m, both in the Viewer and in the camera properties. Increase this value to a reasonable distance so that the load to the gpu is not affected.

[Camera lens documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cameras.html#lens)

[View Panel Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/sidebar.html#view-panel)

[image: Clipping distance]